# How to run the exe file in visual studio command prompt for Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

1. How can i execute the .exe file in the Visual Studio 2012 command prompt. I am using the Visual Studio express edition

How it is possible?

Regards,

Prasad

Comment: What do you mean by "execute the .exe file"? You just run it... If it's test.exe, you can change to that directory and then run "test". Please clarify your question.

Comment: Is there an alternative way for Visual Studio 2012 command prompt in Express editions?

Comment: I don't remember offhand whether it provides one out of the both, but I usually find that just including the relevant framework directory in my PATH environment variable does almost everything I'd need.